# Chef: How to reference/perform operations on a directory after creating it in the same recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I need to create a directory then copy the files to the newly created directory via same recipe (do not need 2 recipes - 1 for creation and another for copying) . But when I am doing it, 2nd part of recipe where files needs to be copied it is failing giving error message : directory does not exist. 
From the error its conclusive that it is failing during compile time as directory is not there because it will be created in the first step
Please advise

```rb
dir="/ibmlib"
directory '/ibmlib' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0777'
  action :create
end

li = 'add file'
clrlog1 = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/ibmlib')
clrlog1.insert_line_if_no_match(/#{li}/, li)
clrlog1.write_file
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @StephenKing

dir="/ibmlib"
directory '/ibmlib' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0777'
  action :create
end

li = 'add file'
clrlog1 = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/ibmlib')
clrlog1.insert_line_if_no_match(/#{li}/, li)
clrlog1.write_file

Comment: Do you want it to be a directory or a file? You should wrap ruby code inside the [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) resource. Otherwise it is executed "too early".

Comment: @StephenKing    The requirement is to create a directory then create files within this directory and then edit these files with some content

Comment: Do you know the [`template`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) resource? If you completely manage the file using Chef (as it didn't exist before..) that's the way clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the directory path stored as an attribute, something like:

```
directory node['attribute']['new_path'] do
  recursive true
end

execute 'copy' do
  command "cp #{node['attribute']['old_path']}/* #{node['attribute']['new_path']}/."
end
```

Please keep in mind that the order the resources are called is vital here, so if you have other resource notifying these, keep an eye on the order when they are requested to be executed (Like having one with delayed execution).

Just to be sure on the order you could try this too:

```
directory node['attribute']['new_path'] do
  recursive true
  notifies :run, 'execute[copy]', :immediate
end

execute 'copy' do
  command "cp #{node['attribute']['old_path']}/* #{node['attribute']['new_path']}/."
  action :nothing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you should really avoid in-line file editing because it results in brittle recipe code. If you must do it, use the `line` cookbook as it provides resource-oriented versions of the code you showed, which works better with Chef-y stuffs.